# php - for loop takes only the first value from mysql result

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

In this code I'm trying to create as many modal boxes as the rows of my query result. This works! Then I want to fill these modal boxes with as many checkboxes as the number `$row['seats_no']` from database. Here we have a problem..in every modal box it creates the same amount of checkboxes as the first one. What I mean is that the `$row['seats_no']` has the number from the first row in every row.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name']) && !isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_SESSION['cash'])){
        header("location: Start.php");
    }
    $name=trim($_SESSION['name']);
    $email=trim($_SESSION['email']);
    $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query($dbc,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($dbc,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

    if (isset($_POST['buy']) && isset($_POST['consert_id'])){
        $q = "SELECT ticket_id, section, cost, seats_no FROM tickets INNER JOIN concert ON tickets.consert_id=concert.concert_id WHERE concert.concert_id=".$_POST['consert_id'];
        //ticket_id, concert_id, section, cost, seats_no, concert_id,concert_name, date, place, category, description
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
        $num= mysqli_num_rows($r);
        $q1 = "SELECT * FROM concert WHERE concert_id=".$_POST['consert_id'];
        $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc,$q1);
        $first = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1)
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Seats</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="seats_style.css">
<body>
<div style="z-index:1;position:fixed;">
<ul>
    <li><a href="Concerts.php" class="active">E-Viva</a></li>
    <li><a href="cash.php">Ανανεωση υπολοιπου</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="background">
    <div class="transbox">
        <div class="w3-container">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/199011/concert.png">
            <h1><?=$first['concert_name']?></h1>
            <div style="left:0;"><?=$first['date']?></div>
            <div style="right:0;"><?=$first['place']?></div>
            <p><?=$first['description']?></p>
          <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
            ?>
            <div style="margin-left:5em;padding:5px;"><?=$row['section']?></div>
            <div style="margin-left:5em;padding:5px;">Τιμή <?=$row['cost']?>€</div>
            <div style="margin-left:5em;padding:5px;"><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Κράτηση</button></div>

          <div id="id01" class="w3-modal" background="black">
            <div class="w3-modal-content">
              <div class="w3-container">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
                <p><h2>Διαλεξε τις θεσεις που θες</h2></p>
                <form action="buy.php" method="post">
                <table>
          <?php
          $num=0;
            for($j=1; $j<=10; $j++){
                echo "<tr>";
                for($i=1; $i<= $row['seats_no']/10; $i++){
                    $num++;
                    echo "<td><input class='seat' type=\"checkbox\" name=\"s[]\" id=\"".$num."\" value=\"".$num."\"><label for=\"".$num."\">".$num."</label><input type='hidden' name='ticket_id' value='".$row['ticket_id']."'><input type='hidden' name='cost' value='".$row['cost']."'></td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table><input class=\"ok\" type=\"submit\" name=\"ok\" value=\"Κράτηση\"></form></div></div></div><br>";
            }
            }
            mysqli_free_result($r1);
            mysqli_free_result($r);
            mysqli_close($dbc);
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[here are the results i get from executing my query at phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lQaH.png)

[Here are the buttons I create to open the modals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEADl.png)

[And here is the modal from the last button i clicked that in the database shows it should be 60 checkboxes but it shows 180](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PEqe.png)

Comment: maybe you can add a capture of your modal !!

Comment: can you please put your database result screenshot to our here

Comment: It looks right.. You sure they are different values for `seats_no` in the database?

Comment: What is the meaning or what did you want to this $row['seats_no']/10

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @Kamlesh Solanki I'm trying to show the checkboxes by 10 so that they all appears at the modal.

Comment: @Tegito123 i edit my post and put some screenshots for you to understand it better if possible

Answer (score 0):

Κατερίνα,
Try to change the `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {...}` with a `foreach` loop,
like as `foreach( mysqli_fetch_array($r) as $row ) {....}`
Just a thought.
Also, you close one bracket too soon, remove one before the first `mysqli_free_result($r1)` and close it after the closing html tag  `</html>` at the end of the file.
Also, as @tadman said, do some research and use parameterized queries. Your code it's very prone to MySQL Injections and you will face several problems. As far as i can see that page has to do with payments, or pre-payment.

Anyways, i hope i helped you.
Καλή επιτυχία ;)

Comment: doesn't work...!I've tried with `foreach` and with `for` but the problem remains...Thank you for your time though!!:)